# Value cannot be null exception when trying to run Imageresizer

Tags: imageresizer

I get the following error when trying to run my Image Resizer using my rest api plugin with this urL: http://localhost:8001/D1900010012059

Plugin code can be found here: https://github.com/mikaelekstrom/resizerapiplugin/blob/master/RestAPIImageRetriever.cs

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value

Source Error: 


 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 



[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value]
   System.String.StartsWith(String value, StringComparison comparisonType) +598
   ImageResizer.Storage.BlobProviderBase.FileExists(String virtualPath, NameValueCollection queryString) +88
   ImageResizer.Plugins.VirtualPathProviderShim.GetVIP(String virtualPath) +217
   ImageResizer.Plugins.VirtualPathProviderShim.FileExists(String virtualPath) +23
   System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.IsRouteToExistingFile(HttpContextBase httpContext) +120
   System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext) +129
   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase context) +70
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +139
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +195
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +88
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [`VirtualFilesystemPrefix`](https://github.com/imazen/resizer/blob/869e3ebe5c7e99a42df60769186358979c19327d/Plugins/ImageResizer.Storage/BlobProviderBase.cs#L170) property on the base class to set up routing for your class. You class will handle all requests going to that prefix.